# Please help me master particles

Tags: particles, spoken-language, sentence-final-particles

What would be your recommendation to dominate the japanese particles? I'm tired of my sentences and my speaking being destroyed by the fault of a little stupid particle. I'm studying the minna no nihongo book and i'm starting the lesson 16 but i'm still having problems with these particles!

Comment: Well, it's unlikely one answer will help you with all the particles.  Have you studied any other foreign languages?  If not, your first language can be a challenge, particularly one so different from English.  I would recommend you focus questions here to certain particles that are giving you difficulty.  Some of the particles come in pairs such as で and に as one pair or に and へ as another pair.  Check out the site for questions relating to such pairs.  Hopefully other particles like を are not too difficult since as a beginner you only need to use it to mark the direct object of the sentence.

Comment: [Find a good book.](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=japanese+particles)

Comment: Is not my first language actually, my first language was "español"  tengo un manejo excelente de este idioma a nivel nativo y mi pronunciacion es perfecta. Pero el japones no tiene comparacion.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very subjective answer but, there is no "quick fix" for particles, as there are many exceptions, special cases, etc.  Mastery takes a long time, even if you focus on it.

Consider prepositions in English, which fulfill a similar role.  Why do we play "on" a tennis court, "at" a park, and "in" a sand box?  It feels easy to a native speaker, but it is hard to give/explain a rule that always works, and L2 learners will struggle.

I suggest you focus on learning how to use particles well enough to understand and make yourself understood, and then gain mastery over time by paying attention to them as you read and write (preferably a lot).  This will take years, but that is not unusual.

In general, mastering the small number of functional/adverbial components commonly used in a new language is actually harder and more time consuming than building up a core noun/adjective/verb vocabulary of several thousand.. which may be surprising/discouraging if this is your first time seriously studying a second language, but is quite normal.

For example, and maybe some perspective, I am in my 5th year of Japanese study, conversational, working for a Japanese company, have a vocab in excess of 10k words, read multiple full length books, etc.. and still make basic particle errors daily. It takes time.

Comment: So particles are harder than kanji? How much it will take me to master the particles or the japanese language itself if i study around 12 - 16 (sometimes 18 hours) hours a day? I know that it would be better to go to japan. And live there while i'm learning japanese but its too expensive.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "harder" and by "kanji". But if you mean learning enough about kanji to read everyday texts fluently, then both are hard, and both take years, at least in my experience.  But many kanji are more straightforward, in the sense that you can brute force memorize sample words and develop a decent kanji vocabulary in a systematic way with spaced repetition. 10 new kanji worth of sample words per day plus review is an aggressive but doable pace, and gives you a solid base for reading within a year.  Grammar is not as easy to 'systematize'.